# JSch on z/OS - invalid key when connecting to localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssh, mainframe, zos

I'm working on a SpringBoot application running on z/OS natively (not in a zCX container).
The idea is to maintain a session to a PROTECTED RACF service id using ssh key private/public key pair.

I've set the user, the USS directory and the keys are in the right places.

Here is the interesting bit - I've written the application for easy of testing that runs locally on my corporate laptop. I've targeted in it the inbound address of the z/OS and the same exact private key as when running on z/OS natively(therefore I'm sure the key format is correct). Everything works as expected and I'm able to connect using this key.

However when I package the application to a jar file and run it on z/OS I get

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey
```

The service ID that is running the SpringBoot application on z/OS has access to the private key used when using `jSch.addIdentity()` - I know this because I changed the owner of the key and tested it out. Got a ICH408I message stating the user doesn't have access to the private key(reverted back after testing).

After few days of scratching my head and testing out lots of access setups I've decided to test out if I'm even able to establish a SSH session to this ID from within z/OS - no problems here.

I've also set a password to service ID that is used to run the SpringBoot application. Logged to it and ran `ssh XXXXXX@localhost -i private_key` without any problems. Therefore I'm pretty sure that this is somehow related to a JSch library problem.

Anyone ever came a cross something like that ?

Comment: It is a case of EBCDIC vs. ASCII? Are you able to compare if the `privatekey` mutated on z/OS?

Comment: @paulywill 99.9% it's not the case of the conversion. I've logged on to USS directly and using the same private key managed to logon via SSH to the service ID - both on the inbound IP and the localhost. So I know the key works and the SSHD are set up correctly. 
Additionally I've managed to setup JSch.Logger to get normal ssh clients -v option working.  
When running in windows and targeting inboud IP I the whole verbose stack:
`Authentication succeeded (publickey)`
When running same jar on z/OS I only get:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey`

Comment: So I've also regenerated new key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM` and moved it to the authorized_keys for user. After moving the key to my PC I managed to SSH to the service ID using the new key via the command line and JSch. I can also do it via command line on the lpar targeting the localhost SSHD. However again I cannot logon to the localhost SSH via JSch application running on z/OS.

Answer (score 1):

It works!

The problem was that I've created the key pair in the USS session and transfered them for testing, to my windows machine using VSCode zExplorer plugin.
Seems that this plugin does already a transfer back and fourth with ASCII and EBCDIC character sets.

I reviewed the keys and they were identical - but I was trying to use a mainframe java program using a EBCDIC generated key.

Turns out that SSHD daemon has already engraved that although it runs on z/OS which is a EBCDIC system it expects always a ASCII key.

After converting the key to ASCII using iconv all works as it should

```
iconv –f IBM-1047 –t ISO8859-1 id_rsa > id_rsa_ascii
```

@paulywill Thanks for hinting me where to look.